# Unboxing object containing a value which is known to be assignable to an integer variable

Tags: c#

If I have an `object` instance and I know it is actually a boxed integer, then I can simply cast it back to int like this:

```
object o = GetSomethingByName("foo"); 
int i = (int)o;
```

However, I don't actually know that the value is an integer. I only know that it can be assigned to an integer. For example, it could be a `byte`, and the above code would throw `InvalidCastException` in that case. Instead I would have to do this:

```
object o = GetSomethingByName("foo"); 
int i = (int)(byte)o;
```

The value could also be a `short`, or something else which can be assigned to an `int`. How do I generalize my code to handle all those cases (without handling each possibility separately)?

Comment: @Lasse: the objects are actually produced by an interop layer for an API which works with COM variants. The existing native code on both sides of the API is tolerant of different types of integers, so I try to match that behavior. These variants are also stored in files which are already in the field, and therefore cannot be changed easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply writing the question made me remember that there is a `Convert` class. This seems to work:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(o);
```

**edit**: but unfortunately, it will also do type conversions that I actually don't want, like parsing strings.

Comment: Just what I was suggesting :) You don't need the cast to int though; the method is declared to return an int already.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the unnecessary cast.

Answer (score 2):

It is interesting to see how `Convert.ToInt32` accomplishes the conversion:

```
    public static int ToInt32(object value) 
    {
        return value == null? 0: ((IConvertible)value).ToInt32(null); 
    }
```

The trick is to cast the object to `IConvertible`.